# Find center of a view without creating a custom view

Tags: android, android-view

This is really quite a simple task but all of the solutions I have looked at seem to point me towards creating a custom view which extends imageview. Which is frankly ridiculous. Here is what I want to do:

My animation:

```
public void spin() {

    float centerX = imageview.getX() + (imageview.getWidth()/2);
    float centerY = imageview.getY() + (imageview.getHeight()/2);

    Animation animation = new RotateAnimation(0, 360, centerX, centerY);
    animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);

    imageview.setAnimation(animation);
    imageview.animate();

}
```

My view:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:src="@mipmap/app_icon"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/progressbar"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

getX(), getY(), getWidth() and getHeight() all return 0 at every stage of the fragment lifecycle(onCreateView, onStart, onResume and onActivityCreated).

#### Is it possible to get the center of my view without creating a custom view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to get your `View's` dimensions in your `Fragment` lifecycle methods is not the right way to go. The easiest way you can do it is to use `ViewTreeObserver`, like this:

```
mYourImageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
       int width = mYourImageView.getWidth();
       int height = mYourImageView.getHeight();
        if (width > 0 && height > 0) {
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
              mYourImageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
              mYourImageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }

            //now you've got your dimensions.

        }
    }
});
```